# Cached query behavior changes between CF 10 and CF 2016

Tags: coldfusion

I am upgrading from Adobe CF10 to CF2016 and noticed that in CF2016 modifications to a cached query object appear to be persisted back to cache. This does not appear to be the case in CF10.

For example:

```
<cfquery datasource="myDs" name="rs" cachedwithin="#createtimespan(0,0,5,0)#">
    SELECT 10 AS value
</cfquery>

<cfset rs.value = 2016>

<cfquery datasource="myDs" name="rs" cachedwithin="#createtimespan(0,0,5,0)#">
    SELECT 10 AS value
</cfquery>

<!--- CF10 outputs 10 --->
<!--- CF2016 outputs 2016 --->
<cfoutput>#rs.value#</cfoutput>
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? I couldn't find this documented anywhere. RTFMs welcome.

Comment: You seem to understand it.  Upgrades are always adventurous.  I suggest acknowledging the change and change whatever code is affected.

Comment: If you add a column (using `AddQueryColumn()`) before re-performing the cached query, the new column is not cached... so changing an existing value in a query is now cached, but adding a new column is not?

Comment: I've reported this issue to an Adobe ColdFusion engineer using Slack. It's been over a week and I'm still waiting for a response.

Comment: I [created a bug report](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198816) as well, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: @LittleBobbyLoblaw After ~20 days I finally got a response. Adobe indicated that they would be fixing it and "logging that in sometime". I proactively added it to the bug tracker on Monday and on Tuesday they changed the status to "ToFix" and indicated it would be in HF5. I'm pretty surprised that a bug like this made it through their QA testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's define a query object, name it `variables.rs` and place it into cache.

```
<cfquery datasource="myDs" name="rs" cachedwithin="#createtimespan(0,0,5,0)#">
    SELECT 10 AS value
</cfquery>
```

This query object contains one record and one column (named `value`). If we output the value of this one record's column, referenced as `variables.rs.value`, we see the value of `10`.

Now, let's define a `struct` named `variables.rs`, with a single key named `value` and a value of `2016`. If we output this value, referenced as `variables.rs.value`, we see the value of `2016`.

Finally, let's run that query again.

```
<cfquery datasource="myDs" name="rs" cachedwithin="#createtimespan(0,0,5,0)#">
    SELECT 10 AS value
</cfquery>
```

But the query was run within the time of `cachedwithin` and the recordset never changed, so there's no need to update the query cache. Therefore, the variable `variables.rs` will not be updated.

This leaves `variables.rs` as a struct, with the key named `value`, whose value is `2016`.

This seems to be the correct progression of events that should occur. It was probably a bug in previous versions that caused them to act as they did, which was fixed in 2016 (yay!?).

It's likely that [no one has created a bug report](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/home) outlining this exact problem with steps to recreate, therefore, the CF development team doesn't know this is a thing.

Of couse, it might just be easier for you to refactor your code than to hold your breath waiting for the issue to be triaged, accepted, fixed and released. But you could at least give it a shot. My company has filed a number of major changes in funcitonality between 2016 and previous versions and had most, if not all of them fixed.

Comment: CF2016 actually introduced a bug. `cfquery` is supposed to return a result regardless of how the data was retrieved. Documentation says `If original query date falls within the time span, cached query data is used.`. Although it falls within the time span, the cached query data is not returned. It's a bug.

Comment: CF doesn't need to re-run the query (or update the query cache).  It should update the variable "rs" with the cached results and not assume that the assigned variable's value is forever constant during the timespan.  It's a variable "name" assignment parameter and not a "cache key".  That's how it's supposed to work, right?  I sure hope this is a bug and gets fixed as we are migrating to CF2016 soon-ish.

Comment: After ~20 days of communicating w/Adobe on Slack, I finally got a response. They indicated that they'd be fixing it and "logging that in sometime". I proactively added it to the bug tracker on Monday 7/3 and on Tuesday 7/4 they changed the status to "ToFix" and indicated it would be in HF5. I'm pretty surprised that a bug like this made it through their QA testing in the first place.  Here's the bug report: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198980